# Python: How do I take user input and find the highest and lowest numbers?

Tags: python, list, average

I need to write a program that finds the highest and lowest values from the input given by the user.
I have a program that takes  the numbers and names given by the user and sorts them into a list like this:

```
[['Name', 'Score'], ['Name', 'Score'], ['Name', 'Score'], ['Name', 'Score'], ['Name', 'Score']]
```

I need to know how to take this list and read each score, before pulling out the highest and lowest one. Then I need a program that takes all of those scores and gets the mean average of all of them.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you taking user input or parsing a list?

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? If this is homework, you're not going to get much out of it by asking us to do the work for you.

Comment: a bit of both.
I take the user input and organize it into that list. Then I need to parse through that list and find the highest and lowest score.

Comment: I've tried doing max and min, but that failed. Other than that, I don't know too many functions I could use.

Comment: You're on the right track @Ctrl-C. `max` and `min` both accept keys a.k.a custom functions used to find the maximum or minimum in a list. What you need to do is create a function that accepts an element of your scores list, and tells `max` or `min` what part of the element it should use to find the maximum or minimum.

Comment: Put your existing code here. That would be useful to people in seeing what you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

This function would ask for user inputs and return a list of name, score. It can be called multiple times to accept input from more users. Just append the list to the main list.

```
def get_input():
    '''append this list to the main list that is holding the user inputs'''
    name, score = input("what is your name"), input("what is your score")
    return [name, float(score)]
```

If the second part needs to be put in a function, you can put that together as you please. I hope I didn't just do your homework for you...

```
sorted_list = sorted(a_list, key=lambda _: _[1], reverse=True)
high_score, low_score = sorted_list[0], sorted_list[-1]

avg_score = sum([_[1] for _ in a_list]) / len(a_list)
```